# imap not working in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

I wanted to create a keymap in Vim to insert a new line below the current line, without having to exit the Insert mode, just like in Visual Studio Code.

```
imap <C-CR> <Esc>o
```

But this is not working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What does your terminal send when you press Ctrl-Return?

Comment: It was doing just what pressing Return would do.
Anyway, I resolved this by doing a little more research.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for the solution to this problem for the past couple of days and I found the answer today.

For me, this worked:

```
inoremap ^@ <Esc>o
```

Remember, the `^@` is when I press `Ctrl+V`, followed by `Ctrl+Enter`.

Feels weird to be answering my own question.